# Unqualified XML-element with prefixed namespace inside

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following XML:

```
<ns1:verifySignedDocumentResponse xmlns:ns1="http://signing.ws.comarch.gov">
    <verifySignedDocumentReturn xmlns:ns2="http://exception.ws.comarch.gov">Some string content...</verifySignedDocumentReturn>
</ns1:verifySignedDocumentResponse>
```

In `verifySignedDocumentReturn` case I'm wondering, is it correct to define the prefix (`xmlns:ns2=...`), but *not* to qualify (`ns2:verifySignedDocumentReturn`) the appropriate element with this prefix?

w3schools.com [gives examples](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp), which show:

1. If element is prefixed, namespace for the prefix must be defined.
2. Element should't be prefixed, if default namespace is used.

But in my example there is no default namespace. So, I expect `verifySignedDocumentReturn` to be prefixed with `ns2`.

I've got this XML-snippet from real service, so I wonder: is it correct and valid? Or just service creators' carelessness? I ask, because I'm new to XML/XSD.

I've tried to generate XSD from this XML with different online-generators, but no generated schema looks reasonable.

Variant 1 (does not take into account `ns2` namespace at all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://signing.ws.comarch.gov" 
           xmlns:ns1="http://signing.ws.comarch.gov">
   <xs:element name="verifySignedDocumentResponse">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="verifySignedDocumentReturn" form="unqualified" 
                    type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Variant 2:

schema0.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns1="http://signing.ws.comarch.gov" 
           xmlns:ns2="http://exception.ws.comarch.gov" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://signing.ws.comarch.gov" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="verifySignedDocumentResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="verifySignedDocumentReturn" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

schema1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="verifySignedDocumentReturn" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is the declaration of `xmlns:ns2="http://exception.ws.comarch.gov"` in your XML document does nothing. Its just defining an alias ns2, which is never used.

Both the generated schemas look OK. A few notes about them though.

Although the first schema fits neatly in a single XSD, typically the `elementFormDefault` is set to `qualified` and not changed within the schema. In this schema the `form` is being set to `unqualified` for the inner element. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that a validating XML parser using this schema will treat `verifySignedDocumentReturn` as if its in the namespace "http://signing.ws.comarch.gov". I think changing the `form` in the middle of a XSD document is asking for incompatibility issues.

The second set of schemas look OK.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Although these generated schemata look fine, none of them fully comply with the final XML-document. Also I understand, that `xmlns:ns2="...` does nothing. It was SOAP-server response, which should be just parsed, not sent anywhere. So, what is your resolution? _Can I consider that XML-snippet as bad practice example or it is useful for something? And, if useful, for what?_